# How to remove packages from the apt cache that are not currently installed?

Tags: apt, package-management, cache

I want to organise my apt cache folder so I want to **remove** packages that are **NOT currently installed** and **keep** packages that are **ONLY currently installed**

Answer (score 1):

Use `apt-get clean` command.According to man page it cleans downloaded packages which are not longer needed. Also in Synaptic on the low left click Status button and then on up left you will see not installed.Select it and you will do what you want.

Comment: apt-get man page http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get .How is it too hard to understand?

Comment: @Alvar improved answer according to your sugegstions.What do you think? (Also I cant ask new questions anymore because of your downvote D:

Comment: @Alvar would you consider upvoting so I can ask new questions here?

Comment: I didn't down vote your answer...

Comment: @Alvar ok sorry. can you upvote my answer?

Comment: @Alvar I cant ask new questions anymore.. even though I now have 39 reputation because of helping everyone I could.What should I do?

Comment: Hello user251046, please read the information on `How do I write a good answer?`http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer It is nice, that you have a good intention towards helping others, by answering the Q, but there's always room for improvement.

Comment: My answer actually solves the question!Why EXACTLY did you downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote you either to be perfectly honest.

Answer (score 0):

I use [GtkOrphan](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/gtkorphan.html), which does the job nicely.

> GtkOrphan (a Perl/Gtk2 application for debian systems) is a graphical tool which analyzes the status of your installations, looking for **orphaned libraries**. It implements a GUI front-end for deborphan, adding the package-removal capability.

[image]